# Get requests in WCF without method name

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, http-post

Our partner says he is going to send data using the SOAP protocol without using any service name to post data, like `HelloWorld(string p1)`, just a POST.

So I am wondering how is it possible to do with SOAP?

I mean in WCF / web services, we need the name of method anyway, right?

Any clues? Thank you!

**UPDATE #1**

Using **Wireshark** I am getting this message

```
POST HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml
User-Agent: SOAP Sender v1.2
Host: 191.126.125.5:1212
Authorization: Basic QFNLVXNlcjE4MTghOiBAU0tQYTE5MTkh
Content-Length: 708

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <ws:PutCoord>
        <ObjectID>SG255108374</ObjectID>
    </ws:PutCoord>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So what sort of .NET application I have to create to get this POSTED data?
This correspond to https://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part0/#L26866

Comment: yes can achieve that by making restful service , that my guess

Comment: @PranayRana Thank you! Please provide any example.

Comment: @PranayRana SOAP means it is not REST. SOAP implies that there will be a WSDL which means the service will have a name. Secondly there is NO SOAP protocol. SOAP is a set of technologies mainly WSDL, XML and HTTP that is used together.  I suspect the other side might be using XML as the protocol.

Comment: @Namphibian - yeah , agree with you...rest will not go with soap

Comment: @PranayRana Please have a look at my updated question.

Comment: @Namphibian Please have a look at my updated question.

Comment: I think you need to create a procedure name in your server side service. And the client posts the data where is defined in soap body to invoke the procedure.

Comment: @HsuWeiCheng Hi! Please clarify your idea. I cannot get what is ` procedure name in your server side service `... Whoud you give me some example, please?

Comment: @HsuWeiCheng Sorry it is unclear...

Comment: For example: A client posts the data to the server where method name called"Authorize" (Client), the server side must implement a entry to consume the data, e.g. AuthorizeResponse Authorize(AuthorizeRequest request). Client side posted data looks like<s:Header><a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">/Authorize</a:Action></s:Header>, also attached the payload in your soap body.

Comment: @HsuWeiCheng Yeah... I know it but in my question you see exactly what I am getting... Our partner send it it directly to ipaddress:port without any method name. I cannot get how to catch properly in .NET those messages. For instance `body` has  `PutCoord` node. Shall I create service with that name or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was misled by my client HelpDesk. :)

They send data in **SOAP** format using **HTTP** to some port and thats it.

So... Sometimes HelpDesk is gonna confuse you. Hahahaha! Be careful!